# Matrix-vector product like multiplication in Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am currently facing this problem.
I have two matrixes MatrixXf
A:

```
     0.5      0.5      0.5      0.5
0.694496 0.548501 0.680067 0.717111
0.362112 0.596561 0.292028 0.370271
 0.56341 0.642395 0.467179 0.598476
```

and B

```
0.713072
0.705231
0.772228
0.767898
```

I want to multiply them like matrix x vector to achive:

```
     0.5*0.713072      0.5*0.713072      0.5*0.713072      0.5*0.713072
0.694496*0.705231 0.548501*0.705231 0.680067*0.705231 0.717111*0.705231
0.362112*0.772228 0.596561*0.772228 0.292028*0.772228 0.370271*0.772228
 0.56341*0.767898 0.642395*0.767898 0.467179*0.767898 0.598476*0.767898
```

Is there an option to do that in Eigen?  How can do that a simply way?
http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication

Answer (score 6):

This has been asked so many times, you want a scaling:

```
MatrixXf A;
VectorXf B;
MatrixXf res = B.asDiagonal() * A;
```

or using broadcasting:

```
res = A.array().colwise() * B.array();
```

Answer (score 2):

In short you want to do an element-wise product between each column of `A` and vector `B`.

There are at least two ways of accomplishing this:

- iterate over each column of `A` to do an element-wise product with `B` (in eigen referred to as coefficient-wise product)
- replicate your `B` vector into a matrix with the same size as `A` and perform an element-wise product between `A` and the new matrix obtained from vector `B`.

Here's a quick and dirty example based on Eigen's `cwiseProduct()` and `replicate()` functions:

```
auto C = A.cwiseProduct( B.replicate<1,4>() );
```

Comment: Be careful, it is strongly discouraged to use `auto` here, see [why](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html).

Comment: I've used Your idea with replicate but it is not working as I wanted. I will try with iterations. Thank You all for answers.